# Vue.js inline template error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use `inline-template` with `vue.js 2.0`.

I use it with `Laravel blade 5.4`:

```
<users inline-template>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $user->name }}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{ $user->last_name }}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{ $user->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                </td>

                @if($user->isActive())
                    <td>
                        <span class="tag is-success">Ja</span>
                    </td>
                @else
                    <td>
                        <span class="tag is-danger">Nee</span>
                    </td>
                @endif

                <td>
                    <span class="tag is-warning">Admin</span>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</users>
```

**Vue component:**

```
  <script>
        export default {
            created() {
                alert('test');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**App.js:**

```
Vue.component('users',                          require('./components/user/Users.vue'));
```

But I get the error as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
>       at genInlineTemplate

What could be wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to use an `inline-template` with a single file component? I don't think thats going to fly. Single file components require a template that is compiled into a render function.

Comment: @BertEvans hi, thanks for your response. I used the inline-template before like this. No idea why it suddenly throws that error. A template it not required if you use ```inline-template``` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates

Comment: What's your complete .vue file? Just script?

Comment: @BertEvans Yes it is.

Comment: Go figure; it does work. I... have no idea why you would do that and not just use a javascript file for the component, but there you have it. The only thing I can think of causing this particular error may be something not rendering correctly from php.

Comment: @BertEvans I think you can't say it's a bad thing. If you are not building a SPA application it can be useful, for example with authentication.

Comment: I don't think `inline-template` is a bad thing. I meant that in your case you are making a single file component (a .vue) file that only has script. The main reason to use a single file component is to keep the `template` and the `script` together. You could convert your single file component into a javascript file without any repercussions (because it doesn't *have* a template). Unless, I guess, you are overriding a default template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline template doesn't seem to latch onto `<tr>` tags very well.

I couldn't find any explaination in the docs but solved the issue by wrapping in a `<div>` tag.

```
<component inline-template>
     <div>
          <tr>
             <th>Something</th>
             <th>something</th>
             <th>something</th>
          </tr>
     </div>
</component>
```